# Create a login link without a password in node js

Tags: node.js

I have a site and I want to register users so that they first enter the email, then the confirmation email is sent, and then they enter the name and username and there is no need for a password. Enter only one email for site users to log in and a secure email will be sent to them via the API token.

"website.com/api/v1/verify?token"

Is there a way to do that?
nodejs

Comment: "Is there a way to do that?" Yes. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.